# Cannon find module. Electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, electron-packager

got a problem which made me stuck for 3 hours. I'm started learning Electron framework.

Everything worked good before i installed independence : ElectronViewRenderer.

This is error : Cannot find module '../js/index.js'

My folder structure: http://puu.sh/yAbnR/1acdb39aa7.png

My Index.ejs (view) :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <link href="asset://../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a id="home" class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active" id="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li id="page1"><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li id="page2"><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li id="register"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>

    Test


    <script>
      require('../js/index.js');
      window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Packager.json :

```
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "1.7.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "electron-view-renderer": "^1.2.4",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your trying to require the index.js file from index.js?

Comment: I'm trying to require index.js from index.ejs.